# Make all positive value bar graph the same color theme as bar graph with negative values in ggplot

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I just started playing with ggplot yesterday. My code for the bar graph with negative values work as I have expected:

```
dtf1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:10),Diff = c(-5:4))
dtf1$colour <- ifelse(dtf1$Diff < 0, "firebrick1","steelblue")
dtf1$hjust <- ifelse(dtf1$Diff > 0, 1.3, -0.3)
ggplot(dtf1,aes(ID,Diff,label="",hjust=hjust))+
  geom_text(aes(y=0,colour=colour))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="identity",aes(fill = colour))
```

[image: Positive and Negative Value]
But not so when I apply the same code to a different dataset that has only positive values

```
dtf <- data.frame(ID = c(1:10),Diff = rnorm(10,3))
dtf$colour <- ifelse(dtf$Diff < 0, "firebrick1","steelblue")
dtf$hjust <- ifelse(dtf$Diff > 0, 1.3, -0.3)
ggplot(dtf,aes(ID,Diff,label="",hjust=hjust))+
  geom_text(aes(y=0,colour=colour))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="identity",aes(fill = colour))
```

[image: Only positive values]

I find that I can tweak the last line of the code to get blue colors for my positive bars,
`geom_bar(stat="identity",position="identity",fill="steelblue")`

My two questions therefore are:

1. However, the color isn't as expected:

[image: Positive value - to blue]

It seems like the color may be closer to turquoise3 instead of to steelblue.

2. Moreover, I am also interested in finding why the same code would
   allow the positive bars to have different colors.

I must have been asking a very simple question. I don't know how best to phrase it and therefore have difficulty finding the solution. I apologize if the question has already been asked and I would be glad to delete myself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aesthetics don't work that way in `ggplot`. `$colour` is treated as a factor with two levels, `firebrick1`, and `steelblue`, but these are ***not*** the colors `ggplot` uses. They are just the labels for the color scale. `ggplot` picks it's own colors. If you want to override the defaults, add the line:

```
scale_fill_manual(values=c(firebrick1="firebrick1",steelblue="steelblue"))
```

Compare to this:

```
dtf1$colour <- ifelse(dtf1$Diff < 0, "negative","positive")
ggplot(dtf1,aes(ID,Diff,label="",hjust=hjust))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="identity",aes(fill = colour))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(positive="firebrick1",negative="steelblue"))
```

[image]

This works with all positive (or negative).

```
dtf <- data.frame(ID = c(1:10),Diff = rnorm(10,3))
dtf$colour <- ifelse(dtf$Diff < 0,"negative","positive")
dtf$hjust <- ifelse(dtf$Diff > 0, 1.3, -0.3)
ggplot(dtf,aes(ID,Diff,label="",hjust=hjust))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="identity",aes(fill = colour))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(positive="firebrick1",negative="steelblue"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - I really appreciate having one code that works with all graphs. My interpretation of colour was wrong