# How to get a downward directed histogram for negative values in a column?

Tags: r, histogram

I have a column with values ranging from -10 to +10. I want to draw a histogram where negative value frequencies are shown in downward direction and positive values in upwards direction. How to do this?

```
 df8$Difference
  [1]  -2   6   7  -8   6   5   2   4  -3   1   9   3  -4   2   6  -1  11   5   2   8  15
 [22]   0   9  -5   1  16  12  14  -7 -11  -8   1   1  11   6   3   2  -2   8  -5  NA  -5
 [43]   2  10   7   1   9  -5   7   4   5   9  NA  13  -1   2   5   6   9   4   0   3  -4
 [64]   3   2   4  14  -9  12   6   0   6   6  -5  -1  -6  11   2   3   3   5   1  -5   6
 [85]  19  15  -4   9  -1  -4  -4 -10  NA  NA  NA   0   0  15   7 -10   2   0  -5  -5  10
[106]  -2  -8  18   1  -1   7  -5  -9  -6 -18  11  -1  NA  11  -4   7   5  20   3   2   0
[127]   2   2  11  -2  -5   0   6  -2   6  -2  -5  -1  -5  -6   3  -1  -9  -1   9  NA  -6
[148]   4  -5   8   0  -2   1   9   3   9  -3   2   8   0   2  -4   6   4  -5
```

Comment: Maybe this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645067/t-bar-graph-with-negative-values) will be helpful.

Comment: The values range from -18 to  +20, not -10 to 10

Comment: @AllanCameron Yup. I know, but I'm concerned with variation between -10 to +10 only. Hence used that.

Comment: I'd worry about how this would be interpreted. The purpose of a histogram is to show counts in different bins; you wouldn't have negative counts just because you have negative values. If what you really want is to differentiate between positive and negative values, maybe different colors would be a better way that's more true to what your data says. Or a different type of chart.

Comment: @camille I'm comparing the difference between two results in each case. So if difference is positive it will mean that first result was higher than second one. And in cases where second result is higher, difference is negative. Thus upwards(+y) frequencies will be for cases where result one is higher and downwards(-y) frequencies will be for cases where result two is higher. Thus I can differentiate both results easily.

Comment: Right, I get that you might have negative *values*, but that doesn't mean you have negative *counts*. And a histogram is meant to show counts. Just seems like it could become hard to interpret / misleading to show e.g. -23 observations between -3 and -5, where those were actually observed 23 times

Comment: @camille I understand that it does not have negative counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly manipulate a histogram object:

```r
histo <- hist(df8$difference)
```

[image]

```r
histo$counts[1:4] <- -histo$counts[1:4] 
plot(histo)
```

[image]

Reproducible data:

```
df8 <-  structure(list(difference = c(-2, 6, 7, -8, 6, 5, 2, 4, -3, 1, 
        9, 3, -4, 2, 6, -1, 11, 5, 2, 8, 15, 0, 9, -5, 1, 16, 12, 14, 
        -7, -11, -8, 1, 1, 11, 6, 3, 2, -2, 8, -5, NA, -5, 2, 10, 7, 
        1, 9, -5, 7, 4, 5, 9, NA, 13, -1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 4, 0, 3, -4, 3, 
        2, 4, 14, -9, 12, 6, 0, 6, 6, -5, -1, -6, 11, 2, 3, 3, 5, 1, 
        -5, 6, 19, 15, -4, 9, -1, -4, -4, -10, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 15, 
        7, -10, 2, 0, -5, -5, 10, -2, -8, 18, 1, -1, 7, -5, -9, -6, -18, 
        11, -1, NA, 11, -4, 7, 5, 20, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 11, -2, -5, 0, 6, 
        -2, 6, -2, -5, -1, -5, -6, 3, -1, -9, -1, 9, NA, -6, 4, -5, 8, 
        0, -2, 1, 9, 3, 9, -3, 2, 8, 0, 2, -4, 6, 4, -5)), 
        class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -165L))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.